# How to show video/mp2t in HTML?

Tags: html, type-conversion, video-streaming, video-player

I have this stream, which when i try to download show format video/mp2t and keep downloading because it is stream and i cannot get any file like m3u8 or something like that. Here is link of that stream: http://dddaaa.net:80/VladimirMihajlovic8222/bgzfv3XJcC/1484, so my goal is here to show this Stream somehow in HTML like i could some m3u8 streams.

Comment: Look into Media Source Extensions (MSE).  And, you may have to re-mux it to MP4 on-the-fly.

Answer (score -2):

So are you talking about embedding your video so it streams on your site and doesn't download? If that's the case, here's a simple website that will walk you through it:
https://animoto.com/blog/video-marketing/embed-video-on-website/

Comment: I need to embed this kinda of stream to HTML.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.